# How to show bootstrap lightbox after some seconds after clicking

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a gallery in which I have to show lightbox on each image - so I want some delay in that lightbox

Is there any way to do that?

code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.varr', function() {
  var post_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/post-result.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
      post_id: post_id
    },
    success: function(response) {
      //$('#loaddata').html(response);
      $('#loaddata').html(response);
      // alert(response)  
    }
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.remodal').modal('hide');
  }, 3000);

})
```

Comment: You're already using `setTimeout` - can't you use that again?  Either put the `$.ajax` in a setTimeout or put the `$("#loaddata")...` in one.

Comment: i am just trying settimeout function but it is not working

Comment: Please provide fiddle for better understanding.

Comment: Provide static `html` and `jquery` code. So, we solve !

Comment: On re-reading: exactly where do you want the delay?  When you click, delay before showing the item (as I first read it), or delay and then close the lightbox?

Comment: Which part are you having issue with?  Showing the lightbox or hiding it?  Can you tell us which "bootstrap lightbox" plugin you are using?  Most likely you just need to change `$(".remodal"..` to `$(".modal")..`

Comment: when i  click on image...the lightob showing previous image for 2 sec and then update new image...i want that no transition is show in ligthbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this script:

```
   <script>
      $(document).on( 'click', '.varr', function() {
       //Put Loader here
       $('#loaddata').html("");
       var post_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
       $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/post-result.php",
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        data : { post_id : post_id },
        success : function( response ) {
         //Remove loader here 
         $('#loaddata').html( response );

        }
       });
      })
    </script>
```

I hope it will work for you!!